# Modify an existing XML without affecting the other data for AS3 Air application

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3

I am working on an ActionScript 3 AIR desktop application that requires to save data as an XML file in the user's `C:\` drive, in order to be able to read the data saved again after re-opening.

The saving process is fine, the problem arises when I try to re-open the application and try to override an old value, **the whole data saved is removed except the new value**.

I know why the error occurred (based on my code), but I can not find any work around for solving this problem. I want the user to be able to re-open the application and retrieve his old data, and **if he should overwrite an existing data entry then only that specific entry data is the overwritten, not the whole data**.

Here is my code (it is updated after I found the solution):

```
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.filesystem.File;
import flash.filesystem.FileStream;
import flash.filesystem.FileMode;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

var selfEvaluationLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var answersLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var imgLoader = new Loader();
var SEXML:XML;
var loadedXML:XML;
var SECounter = 1;
var degree:Array = new Array();
var saveDegree:Array = new Array();
var letterArr:Array = new Array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","o")
var savedXML:XML;
var saveFlag=true;
var file:File;
var fileStream:FileStream;
var flag1:String;

nextSE.buttonMode = true;
nextSE.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,nextQuestion);
selfEvaluationLoader.load(new URLRequest("selfEval.xml"));
selfEvaluationLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,processSEXML);
for(var b=1;b<5;b++)
    {
        SEAnswer["RB"+b].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,saveAnswer);
    }

function processSEXML(e:Event)
{
    SEXML = new XML(e.target.data);
    imgLoader.load(new URLRequest(SEXML.question.(@id==1).img.children()));
    addChild(imgLoader);
    //imgLoader.visible=false;
}

function nextQuestion(e:MouseEvent)
{
    SECounter++;
    if(SECounter == 15)
    {
        texts.alpha=1;
        nextSE.enabled=false;
        prevSE.enabled=false;
        answersLoader.load(new URLRequest("C:/Users/Safwat/My Documents/xml/saveDegree.xml"));
        answersLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,loadDatafromC);
    }
    else
    {
        prevSE.enabled = true;
        prevSE.buttonMode = true;
        prevSE.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,prevQuestion);
        SEAnswer["hiddenRB"].selected = true;
        imgLoader.load(new URLRequest(SEXML.question.(@id==SECounter).img.children()));
        addChild(imgLoader);
    }
}
function prevQuestion(e:MouseEvent)
{
    SECounter--;
    switch(flag1)
    {
        case "RB1":
        SEAnswer["RB1"].RB1.selected = true;
        break;
        case "RB2":
        SEAnswer["RB2"].RB2.selected = true;
        break;
        case "RB3":
        SEAnswer["RB3"].RB3.selected = true;
        break;
        case "RB4":
        SEAnswer["RB4"].RB4.selected = true;
        break;
        default:
        SEAnswer["hiddenRB"].selected = true;
    }
    if(SECounter == 1)
    {
        nextSE.enabled=false;
        prevSE.enabled=false;
    }
    else
    {
        nextSE.enabled = true;
        //SEAnswer["hiddenRB"].selected = true;
        imgLoader.load(new URLRequest(SEXML.question.(@id==SECounter).img.children()));
        addChild(imgLoader);
    }
}
function saveAnswer(e:MouseEvent)
{
    degree[SECounter-1]=String(e.currentTarget.name);
    flag1=e.currentTarget.name;
    trace("flag1 is "+flag1)
    onAnswer();
}
function onAnswer()
{
    file = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("xml/saveDegree.xml");
    if(file.exists && saveFlag==true)
    {
    trace("here")
    answersLoader.load(new URLRequest("C:/Users/Safwat/My Documents/xml/saveDegree.xml"));
    answersLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,retrieveSavedData);
    }
    else
    {
    saveFlag=false;
    trace("not existed")
    var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
    fileStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
    fileStream.writeMultiByte('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'+'\n'+'<questions>', "iso-8859-01");
    for(var kk=0;kk<14;kk++)
    fileStream.writeMultiByte('<question>'+degree[kk]+'</question>', "iso-8859-01");
    fileStream.writeMultiByte('\n'+'</questions>', "iso-8859-01");
    fileStream.close();
    }
}
function loadDatafromC(e:Event)
{
    nextSE.enabled=false;
    prevSE.enabled=false;
    loadedXML = new XML(e.target.data);
    SEAnswer.alpha=0;
    for(var b=1;b<5;b++)
    {
        SEAnswer["RB"+b].removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,saveAnswer);
    }
    for(var d=0;d<14;d++)
    {
    switch(String(loadedXML.question[d]))
    {
        case "RB1":
        texts[letterArr[d]+"1"].gotoAndStop(2);
        break;
        case "RB2":
        texts[letterArr[d]+"2"].gotoAndStop(2);
        break;
        case "RB3":
        texts[letterArr[d]+"3"].gotoAndStop(2);
        break;
        case "RB4":
        texts[letterArr[d]+"4"].gotoAndStop(2);
        break;
    }
    }
    if(SECounter==14)
    {
        texts.alpha=1;
        answersLoader.load(new URLRequest("C:/Users/Safwat/My Documents/xml/saveDegree.xml"))
        answersLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,loadDatafromC)
    }
}
function retrieveSavedData(e:Event)
{
    savedXML = new XML(e.target.data);
    savedXML.replace(SECounter-1,<question>{degree[SECounter-1]}</question>)
    fileStream = new FileStream();

    var timer:Timer = new Timer(100, 1);
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,timedSave);
    timer.start();
}
function timedSave(e:TimerEvent)
{
    fileStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
    fileStream.writeMultiByte('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'+'\n', "iso-8859-01");
    fileStream.writeMultiByte(savedXML, "iso-8859-01");
    fileStream.close();
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of : **[Loading data after saving on XML for AS3 application](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38824070/2057709)**. Please remove one of them. You can also **edit** your questions if you wish to update any details.

Comment: @VC.One the repeated question is deleted.
I found the answer actually by using the .replace function for an xml object

Comment: +1 for finding own solution. You should post that info about `.replace` function as an answer, since it worked for you. Might help someone.

Comment: Thank you!
The solution was quite simple. I was creating the XML file every time I open the file again, actually all it needs is to check is an XML file is existed or not using `.exist` function which returns true if there is an XML file and false if there is not.
So if the condition is true which means that there is an XML file all it needs is to update it using `.replace` function as follows:

`savedXML.replace(SECounter-1,<question>{degree[SECounter-1]}</question>)`

Comment: **The question is updated with the solution**